# how to correctly use fork, exec, wait

Tags: c, shell, exec

The shell i'm writing needs to execute a program given to it by the user. Here's the very shortened simplified version of my program

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid = getpid(); // this is the parents pid

    char *user_input = NULL;
    size_t line_sz = 0;
    ssize_t  line_ct = 0; 

    line_ct = getline(&user_input, &line_sz, stdin); //so get user input, store in user_input

    for (;;)
    {
        pid_t child_pid = fork(); //fork a duplicate process

        pid_t child_ppid = getppid(); //get the child's parent pid

        if (child_ppid == pid) //if the current process is a child of the main process
        {
            exec(); //here I need to execute whatever program was given to user_input
            exit(1); //making sure to avoid fork bomb
        }

        wait(); //so if it's the parent process we need to wait for the child process to finish, right?

    }
}
```

1. Have I forked the new process & checked to see if it's a child process correctly
2. What exec could I use here for what I'm trying to do? What is the most simple way
3. What are my arguments to wait? the documentation I'm looking at isn't helping much

Assume the user might input something like ls, ps, pwd

Thanks.

Edit:

```
const char* hold = strdup(input_line);
char* argv[2]; 

argv[0] = input_line;
argv[1] = NULL;

char* envp[1];
envp[0] = NULL;

execve(hold, argv, envp);
```

Comment: There are dozens of similar questions like this here on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Here's a simple, readable solution:

```
pid_t parent = getpid();
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == -1)
{
    // error, failed to fork()
} 
else if (pid > 0)
{
    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
else 
{
    // we are the child
    execve(...);
    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   // exec never returns
}
```

The child can use the stored value `parent` if it needs to know the parent's PID (though I don't in this example). The parent simply waits for the child to finish. Effectively, the child runs "synchronously" inside the parent, and there is no parallelism. The parent can query `status` to see in what manner the child exited (successfully, unsuccessfully, or with a signal).

Comment: Ok so from linux man pages: int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]); Could you explain those arguments in the context of my program

Comment: @user2079802: Doesn't the man page explain how `execve` works? You can also use various [other exec interfaces](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl).

Comment: @user2079802: No need for `strdup`. Just `execve(argv[0], argv, envp)` should do.

Comment: In fact, the child can call `getppid()` to get the parent process' ID. No need to save it in advance. :-)

Comment: @AlanHaggaiAlavi: One less system call :-)

Comment: Where the child says "exec never returns" - this isn't quite correct, the documentation says "On success, execve() does not return, on error -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately." So shouldn't the code be:
`if (execve(...) == -1) _exit(errno) else _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);`