# Stop mpg123 after playing the file completely in automatically

Tags: c, linux, fork

First I have used mpg123 remotely using FIFOs to implement Pause functionality, but now I want to close the mpg123 player when file is played through automatically.

The code for playing current is

```
pid p = fork();  
if (p<0)  
  return;  
else if (p==0)  
  execlp("mpg123", "mpg123", "-R", "--fifo", "aFifo", NULL);  
else  
  system("load test.mp3 > aFifo");
```

Currently if the file is played through then also child process **else if (p==0)** will stay there and mpg123 player process will continue to exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `?` in your question, but any way
your code looks wrong, because `system` uses `fork` and `exec`
under the hood. So instead of one `fork` and one `exec`
you use `fork` three times and uses `execv` twice.

Read how to run process here: [how to correctly use fork, exec, wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099663/how-to-correctly-use-fork-exec-wait)

after you run process in proper way, you have real pid of `mpg123`,
and so you can kill it if you want, or pause or what else you want.

Comment: i got ur point and edited the question, i doubt whether similar commands can be used for 2nd command, and my exact question since the mpg123 player is attached to the fifo in child process, now from parents process commands are supplied, so how the status of the player we can get in parent process?