# How to run 2 child processes, but run one subsequent to another in C?

Tags: c, fork, posix, wait, child-process

I am trying to run two pre-made executables within a new program, but run these two original executables each within their own child process, so basically, just make a parent process fork() into two childs.  However, I see A LOT of questions posed regarding running multiple child processes *in parallel*, but I want to run one first, wait for the first to finish, and then run the second.  And maybe this goes without say, but then, afterwards, return to the parent process after the second child is finished (so I can just print some message notifying a user that both executables are finished).  I am very unskilled with using the wait() and waitpid() functions and these are quite critical to what I am trying to do.
Anyway someone could give me a quick sample program that would ensure that one child process runs *subsequent* to the second?  Thank you so much for your time!!

Comment: Wait for the first one before you fork the second one.

Comment: There is an example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19099707/13596037 - do this for the first child, and then do the whole thing again for the second child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
system("command1");
system("command2");
```

This is roughly equivalent to the following:

```
{
   const char* child_argv[] = { "command1", NULL };
   pid_t pid = fork();
   if (!pid) {
      execvp(child_argv[0], child_argv);
      exit(255);  // errno should probably be sent to parent first.
   }

   waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}

{
   const char* child_argv[] = { "command2", NULL };
   pid_t pid = fork();
   if (!pid) {
      execvp(child_argv[0], child_argv);
      exit(255);  // errno should probably be sent to parent first.
   }

   waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}
```

On a POSIX system, you can use `spawn` instead of `fork`.

```
{
   const char* child_argv[] = { "command1", NULL };
   pid_t pid;
   posix_spawnp(&pid, child_argv[0], NULL, NULL, child_argv, environ);
   waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}

{
   const char* child_argv[] = { "command2", NULL };
   pid_t pid;
   posix_spawnp(&pid, child_argv[0], NULL, NULL, child_argv, environ);
   waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}
```

The latter two solutions avoid using a shell (which is a good thing if you have a file name or path rather than shell command).

Of course, all three snippets are lacking error checking.

Comment: `system` invokes a shell. OP hasn't said that they want to do that.

Comment: Fine - apart from the fact that if the exec fails then you will have a lot more happening than you bargained for - put an exit after the exec.

Comment: Since properly handling all of the corner cases is complex, and not really the point of this Q/A, how about using `posix_spawn` instead?